# Prepare SD card for removal from Cyanogenmod 13 HTC Desire HD A9191

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, partitions, htc-desire-hd

I installed CM on the above phone. I wanted to remove the SD card, but when it boots up again the phone says 'Encryption unsuccessful'. It works again if I put the card back in and reboot the phone.

I want to move the SD card to another phone, and have this one without an SD card. I know that it works without an SDcard, but how? Do I need to move the /data partition somehow? How do I do that?

Edit: It was the CM build I used, which was aceopt. The *opt* part means that it uses the SD card as internal storage. So I need another build if I want to take the card out. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a non *opt* version of CM 13 for this device, so I'll have to go with 12.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your SD card in your phone, reboot it, then go to Settings - Storage & USB, press "menu" button and choose "format as portable". You should be able to use your SD card on other devices after that.

Comment: Ok just tried that. Nothing happens when I press the menu button. The button works fine in other contexts, vibrates, etc. When i select storage and usb it comes up with 'internal storage'. In other words, it appears to be using the sd card as the data partition.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that you need to choose "SD card" before prsssing menu button and selecting "format as portable". But, since you only have "internal storage" in there, try choosing it and doing described above there. And you rebooted your phone after inserting your SD card back to it? It is needed for system to recognize SD card inserted on some phones/ROMs.

Comment: Yes, I put it back in, but not really sure what you mean. The phone won't boot up at all unless I have the SD card in. I can't, for example, boot it without the SD card and then boot it with the SD card. There is no option to select SD card. If I select 'Storage and USB' it takes me straight to 'Internal Storage' without asking me what storage I want to configure.

Comment: I was suggesting that in case if SD card was removed from a phone you having troubles with then you better reboot your phone after inserting it. And... I also meant that you should try clicking on "internal storage" then "menu" button and "format as portable" if available. Because, in some old CM13 builds when SD card mounted "as internal", Settings app will display only internal memory (with internal memory and SD card memory summed up) as much, as other applications.

Comment: Right. I think that's what's happened. Only 'internal storage' is displayed. As far as the phone is concerend there isn't an SD card, because it thinks the SD is internal storage and freaks out when it isn't available. And as I said, the SD card doesn't come up as an option and the menu button doesn't produce a menu.

Comment: You can check if your device have SD card merged with internal memory by typing "sm has-adoptable" into Android Terminal. You can download Android Terminal app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm

Comment: That returned 'false'.

Comment: It's not what causes your problem then. Try going to Settings - Security and tell me if there "encrypt phone" option available.

Comment: Yep, that's available. Or it's not greyed out. I didn't press it because I didn't want to actually encrypt it and complicate the situation further. Or do I need to?

Comment: No, you surely  don't need to do it. I just suggested that you turned on encryption and that's why this error on boot is present but it seems like my suggestion was wrong. Did you tried to seek assistance in your device thread on XDA Developers forum? It looks like this could be something specifically related to CM13 build for you phone.

Comment: Good call on the device thread. I was being dumb, see edit.

Comment: Just glad my advice appeared helpful to you. And nothing dumb​ here. You can't be born knowing it all.

Comment: I guess not. There's a lot to read when trying to do stuff like this, and xda has some very good content but it's a dog's dinner in organisational terms. Thanks for your help.